# Conditionally add object to Item's child array in DynamoDB based on unique key

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to conditionally update an Item by pushing an object into an array only if a desired key's value on that object is unique in the context of that array.

Consider the following example model:

```
{
  "id": "1562791912524",
  "title": "DynamoDB for Gummies",
  "description": "database design for gummy candies",
  "authors": [
      {
          "firstName": "Jen",
          "lastName": "Jane",
          "authorId": "1234"
      },
      {
          "firstName": "James",
          "lastName": "John",
          "authorId": "5678"
      }
  ]
}
```

If I were to update this Item with a new object in the `authors` array, the `authorId` would have to be unique to that array.  "4321" would result in a successful update while "1234" would not.  Is there a condition expression that would satisfy this requirement or some other approach?